# Hypernym for "query" and "report"

Tags: semantics

One hypernym for *teacher* and *student* is *person*. *Vehicle* is a hypernym of 
*car* and *lorry*....

Is there a hypernym for *query* and *report*?

Comment: An interchange.?

Comment: Information? : 1)  knowledge communicated or received concerning a particular fact or circumstance.

Comment: I'm wondering what might be the reason for such word problems. I see no practical use for it. Are those questions from a test book or something similar?

Comment: A _query_ is often verbal, whereas a _report_ is usually printed. You need to narrow down senses.

Comment: @rogermue this is quite common in software design where you abstract the shared stuff into parent class.

Comment: It would be good if there was a hint when   questions   arise from programming . As in such questions often terms come up that are not usual in traditional grammar.

Answer (score 2):

Both the query and the report are examples of *communication*.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above, communication fits as a parent word, but more appropriately as a grandparent. To move into a taxonomic metaphor (and supposing we're talking about written communication only (thanks Avon for pointing this out)), if *report*  and *query* are considered **species**, *document* would be their **genus** (parent word) within the **family** of *communication*. But one could claim that there are as many varieties of documents as there are of communication. Perhaps, but in this context *document* is the more specific term because it represents the formal, written type of communication of queries and reports, whereas *communication* doesn't necessarily happen only in written form.

Comment: Queries and reports can be verbal.

Answer (score 0):

Queries and reports are rather distinct entities, so it will probably be more helpful to search for a hypernym for each term separately.

An *account* or a *statement* might be acceptable hypernyms for 'report', as 'report' might be defined:

> a spoken or written account, especially in the form of an official document, of a particular matter that one has investigated or otherwise observed

'Query' can be defined as:

> a question, especially one addressed to an official or other authoritative entity

With that in mind, perhaps a decent hypernym for 'query' would simply be *question*.